# How can Microsoft Graph API be used to read Outlook emails hosted on-premise Exchange servers?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

How can Microsoft Graph API be used to read Outlook emails hosted on-premise Exchange servers? How is it different from exchangelib?

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, when Microsoft Graph identifies that a REST API call is attempting to access an on-premises mailbox in a hybrid deployment, it proxies the REST request to an on-premises REST endpoint which then processes the request. This discovery makes accessing the REST API possible. For more info, [refer the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support).